# Create two random values with javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to store two random numbers between 0 and 10, in two different variables play1 and play2.

The maximum value for play2 will be 10 minus play1 value, ie, if play1 gets 6, maximum value for play2 will be 4.

how can I trigger play2 to store the second value? I need it to be triggered with a second click.

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;


function myFunction() {
  play1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  max = 10 - play1
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = play1;
  
  if (play1 < 10 ) {
    //trigger play2 
  } 
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: simply `play2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;` is it not?

Comment: Hi Jaromanda X, i've edited the question as i forgot to mention i needed the second value to be also triggered by a second click

Comment: clicking the same button? or a different one?

Comment: the same button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself. That's what functions are for:

```js
function r(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
}

var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;

function myFunction() {
  play1 = r(min, max);  
  play2 = r(min, max - (play1-min)); 

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

> i need the second value to be triggered with a second click.

```js
function r(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
}

var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;
var nthClick = 0;

function myFunction() {
  ++nthClick;
  if(nthClick & 1){
    //odd
    play1 = r(min, max);
    play2 = null;
  }else{
    //even
    play2 = r(min, max - (play1-min)); 
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

like this?

Comment: Thats spot on, but now i see I made the wrong question, i need the second value to be triggered with a second click. my apologies for the mistake

Comment: @JoãoMateus I've extended the answer. Better?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply calculate the value of `play2` the same way you calculated the value of `play1` by using - `play2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)) + min;`. I have updated your code below-

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;


function myFunction() {
  play1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  max = 10 - play1
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = play1;
  
  if (play1 < 10 ) {
    play2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)) + min; 
  } else {
    play2 = 0;
  }
  document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = play2;
  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

Comment: Thats spot on, but now i see I made the wrong question, i need the second value to be triggered with a second click. my apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this

```js
var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;


function myFunction() {
    var target = document.getElementById("result");
    var firstNum = parseInt(target.innerHTML);
    if (isNaN(firstNum)) { // first click
        play1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
        target.innerHTML = play1;
    } else {
        play2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((10 - firstNum) - min + 1)) + min;
        // do what with it????? you haven't shown!
        document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = play2;
    }  
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
<p id="result2"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a control to the click count. *Code copied and modified from Thomas' answer*

```js
var controlVariable = 1;

function r(min, max){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max-min+1)) + min;
}

var min = 0;
var max = 10;
var play1;
var play2;

function myFunction() {
  if (controlVariable == 1) {
    play1 = r(min, max);
    controlVariable++; 
  }
  else if (controlVariable == 2) {
    play2 = r(min, max - (play1-min));
    controlVariable = 1;
  }

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = [play1, play2];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: this is it! it works! great tip with the controlvariable, took me a while to get it but i see what you did there. thank you very much Zach A